# Turning the visibility of chart series on/off using excel Macros/vba

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am making a line graph (chart) in Excel with several data series being plotted onto the same chart.

I need to create a macro/VBA solution that can turn the visibilty of these series on/off via the pressing of a button (or tick box etc)

Similar to this picture (manually done through the excel menu system)

[image]

I have tried to look through all the member vars/methods on

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff837379.aspx

but haven't had much luck.

I have tried playing around with bits like

```
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1)
```

and

```
Worksheets("Graphical Data").ChartObjects(1)
```

but I can neither get the chart object ( I get a subscript out of range error) nor able to find any method that would allow me to turn on/off the visibility of individual series.

Any Ideas?

Comment: As you've discovered, there is no `.Visible` property to use. You have to `.Add` and `.Delete` the series.to make them appear and disappear. Do what you did in the image you posted, but with the Macro Recorder running, to figure out how, then update your question with the code you've generated if you're running into a specific issue.

Comment: @FreeMan How is there no `.Visible` property?  that seams really stupid seeing as it obviously exists in the background as the functionality is there through the excel menus...

Comment: You'd have to ask MS about that one. `Chart` has a `.Visible` property, but `.SeriesCollection` does not. If you run Macro Recorder while you're checking those boxes, you'll probably find that the dialog box is essentially recreating the entire `.SeriesCollection` from scratch.

Comment: @FreeMan I tried, and it doesn't record anything.  It records that you have selected the chart and it has activated, but nothing gets recorded for ticking/unticking the visibilty option. Literally nothing.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you there. I think its going to boil down to adding and deleting series in code. Since you've found the MS Docs, finding the `.Add` and `.Delete` (or is it `.Remove` - I don't recall) should be straight forward.

Comment: I agree with @FreeMan about the lack of MS support here.  I would use `Selection.Copy` and `Sheet.Paste` to get a copy of the chart and then remove the `Series` that are not needed.  Doing the `Add/Delete` will get very difficult if there is formatting or anything nonstandard on the chart.  This is especially tough because the default form will remember formatting even if the series is unchecked.  Going through VBA though, the SeriesCollection is definitely shrinking when you uncheck, so the series is being removed.

Comment: I got some simple Macro Recorder code while filtering the chart using the bottom icon to the right of the embedded chart (doesn't parse right in a comment, but whatever):
       
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = True
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = False
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
    
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = False

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Whenever I don't know how to do something like this, I turn on the macro recorder.

I had a chart with four series, and I used the filter function in Excel 2013 to hide and show the second series, while the macro recorder was running.

Here's the relevant code:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = True
' series 2 is now hidden
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).IsFiltered = False
' series 2 is now visible
```

The series type (line or column) does not matter, this works for any of them.

Comment: Great solution, but rather than using `ActiveChart` you could also call the full path `Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = True`

Comment: This is a very good approach, It allows the user to apply filters to the data if one wants to, unlike the accepted answer which hides a series for good.

Comment: I prefer this solution as it also checks/un-checks the box in the Select Data Source menu.  When I tried the accepted solution above, it hid the series but left the box checked in the menu.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the property you are looking for is the `SeriesCollection.Format.Line.Visible` property.  I quickly created an Excel workbook and added a simple data set (just 1-10) and added a line graph "Chart 2" to the sheet Sheet1.

This code turned the visibility of the line off:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ser As Series

    'Retrieve our chart and seriescollection objects'
    Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

    'Set the first series line to be hidden'
    With ser.Format.Line
        .Visible = msoFalse
    End With

End Sub
```

And likewise, setting the `ser.Format.Line.Visible` property to `msoTrue` made the line visible again.

As for retrieving the chart itself I had to first activate it, then set my `cht` variable to the ActiveChart.  To view the name of your chart, select it and look in the name box (near where you would enter the cell value / formula).

### Update

When using the method above, the series name remains in the legend box.  I couldn't find a visibility property for the `SeriesCollection` in the legend, however one workaround is to simply re-name the series as an empty string (this will make the series disappear from the legend) and then rename the series when you want to show it.

This code below will toggle the visibility of the line and series name in the legend.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ser As Series

    'Retrieve our chart and seriescollection objects'
    Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection(1)

    'Set the first series line to be hidden'

    With ser.Format.Line
        If .Visible = msoTrue Then
            .Visible = msoFalse
            ser.Name = vbNullString
        Else
            .Visible = msoTrue
            ser.Name = "Series 1"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

And, whenever you use `.Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue` just remember to set `ser.Name` back to whatever the name for your series is.

Comment: You should be able to `Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Char 2")` with no problem to avoid `Active` anything.  Glad to see this seems possible. I hadn't thought to dig down into the `.Format` options to find it.

Comment: Interesting when I do that, I get a type mismatch, however when I do `Set cht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart` it works.  I will update accordingly.  I only had a hunch because I had to do this on a project a while back, and I recall it being a pain to find the property.  It's buried too deeply IMO (a `.SeriesCollection.Visible` property would make more sense to me).

Comment: ah, yes, makes perfect sense since `Dim cht as Chart`, not `Dim cht as ChartObject`. My bad, you're correct there.

Comment: I'm off to learn what the difference between a `Chart` and `ChartObject` is now.

Comment: You'll hurt your head. You've been warned.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss - The ChartObject is the shape that's embedded in the worksheet. The Chart is the chart that is encapsulated within the ChartObject.

Comment: @joshua Thanks for the help guys,  Nice to see this isn't totally impossible.  There is one difference though between the method you provided.  When seeting the Line.Visible=msoFalse, the name of the data series is still present in the chart legend where as if you use the excel menu checkboxes it dissappears from the legend aswell.  I don't suppose you know the code that could remove (temporarily) the data series name from the legend aswell (which would then return if you called the function  again and set Line.Visible=msoTrue)?

Comment: @JoshuaRoss  Hi, I have just found out that this only works for line graphs.  Is there a solution for Clustered Column graphs as well?

Comment: I downvoted because the OP clearly indicated the process of unchecking the box in front of the series in the Select Data Source dialog, which hides the series by filtering it out of the chart. This answer hides the series by keeping the series in the chart, but using no line to display it, and using vbNullString as its name, so the legend entry is empty but still present. This is not filtering the series out, but simply hiding it with smoke and mirrors.

Comment: If the end result is what is asked for and the OP has indicated his or her problem has been solved by accepting the answer I see no reason to downvote, but thank you for your feedback just the same. Now I know about the `IsFiltered` property.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to on & off the visibility of the series: using filter on your source data.
May it help you easily as follows.
 You can insert a new Window. Setone of them to source data sheet and the other window to Chart sheet. Then arrange the two windows to see both at the same time. Now if you filter the series you like on the source data sheet simultaneously you will see the series you desired on the other sheet.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  Whats a `Window`? Also you don't mention anything about how to do this through a macro?   Regards

Answer (score 0):

The answer for turning on/off visibility of series has already been given, however, if you want to achieve the same for categories (green boxed below)

[image]

the solution is similar but slightly different:

`Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.ChartGroups(1).FullCategoryCollection(2).IsFiltered = True`

So this code will hide the second category (e.g. 2nd bar in a stacked bar chart).