# Excel object chart visible and invisible through VBA

Tags: excel

I want hide the chart on the some specific condition like if corresponding cell is blank the chart should be invisible. but once that cell value is not blank then again chart should be visible.
I have the below program, but it doesnt work for me. please help.

```
Sub chart_visibility()

     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RP0004").Activate
       If Range("H32").Value = "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 5").Visible = False
       Else
        ActiveSheet.Charts("Chart 5").Visible = True
      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703066/turning-the-visibility-of-chart-series-on-off-using-excel-macros-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g:

```
Sub chart_visibility()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RP0004")
       .ChartObjects("Chart 5").Visible = (Len(.Range("H32").Value)>0) 
    End With  
End Sub
```

You want the `ChartObjects` collection and not the `Charts` collection